# How can I solve this dual operational amplifier circuit with nodal analysis?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework, nodal-analysis

[image]

I'm somewhat unsure how to solve the Uout voltage of the above circuit using nodal analysis. Uout being the voltage at the right side obviously. I'm not entirely sure if what I have done so far is correct, but I'm definitely not sure how to continue with my solution. Here is what I've gotten so far:

First I added the voltage source Uin and made a source conversion with the R1 in series.

[image]

J1 is now in parallel with R1 (or G1).

Now I notice that there are 4 nodes in the circuit, so I can create a 4x4 matrix of the form GU=J:

[image]

Here I01 and I02 are the exiting current from their operational amplifiers.

We can remove the rows of I01 and I02:

[image]

Now noticing that U1=U2 and U3=U4, so we can add the their columns together:

[image]

Since U3=U4=Uout, we solve for U3:

[image]

Putting in

[image]

Now gives us

[image]

What do I do now to solve for Uout?

Comment: The case is so simple that it does not require an analysis on a node basis or anything else, but only for educational purposes. It is assumed that the buffer has infinite input impedance, so the output voltage is equal to the input voltage . It follows that the transfer function of the entire system is given by the product of the transfer functions of the two blocks.

Comment: If you want anybody to be able to follow your math, please annotate your schematic so we know what \$U_1\$, \$U_2\$, \$J_1\$, \$G_1\$, etc., are.

Comment: "It follows that the transfer function of the entire system is given by the product of the transfer functions of the two blocks." Can you elaborate on this a bit? I'm not sure how I would use that information to solve for Uout.

Comment: @JohnnyB You have a single pole lowpass filter followed by a single pole highpass filter., each with the appropriate canonical form.  Since they are decoupled by the op-amp buffers, the output is just the product of the two transfer functions, forming a bandpass filter.

Comment: @JohnD Sorry I may sound stupid, but can't I solve the Uout by nodal analysis like I showed above? It's more time consuming in this case, but it's for educational purposes. But like I said, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: @JohnnyB Sure, I didn't mean to imply that you can't solve it using other methods, I was just replying to your question "Can you elaborate on this a bit?" about just multiplying the two trivial transfer functions.  If you do that, you will have an easy check to see if your nodal analysis is correct.

Comment: Because those op-amps are both simple voltage followers, the op amps really shouldn't enter into your equations.

Answer (score 2):

Well, notice that \$\displaystyle\text{V}_{+_1}\$ of the most left OP-AMP is given by:

$$\text{V}_{+_1}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}+\text{R}_1}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\tag1$$

We will get the same for the second OP-AMP:

$$\text{V}_{+_2}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_{+_1}\tag2$$

Using the ideal OP-AMP rule:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\tag3$$

We can see that \$\displaystyle\text{V}_{+_1}=\text{V}_{\text{o}_1}\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{V}_{+_2}=\text{V}_\text{o}\$.

So, we get:

$$\text{V}_\text{o}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}+\text{R}_1}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2}\tag4$$

So, when \$\displaystyle\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$, we get for the amplitude:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|1\right|}{\displaystyle\left|1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right|}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right|}{\displaystyle\left|1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left|1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right|}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\left|1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1^2+\left(\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1^2+\left(\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(1+\left(\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)^2\right)\left(1+\left(\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)^2\right)}}
\end{split}\tag5
\end{equation}

And for the argument:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}\right)+\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(1\right)-\arg\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)+\arg\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)-\arg\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)\\
\\
&=0-\arg\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-\arg\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)\\
\\
&=-\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle1}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)-\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)
\end{split}\tag6
\end{equation}

In the case that \$\displaystyle\text{n}:=\text{C}_1\text{R}_1=\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\$, we get for the amplitude:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(1+\left(\omega\text{n}\right)^2\right)\left(1+\left(\omega\text{n}\right)^2\right)}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(1+\left(\omega\text{n}\right)^2\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{n}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{n}\right)^2}
\end{split}\tag8
\end{equation}

And for the argument:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\omega\text{n}\right)-\arctan\left(\omega\text{n}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arctan\left(\omega\text{n}\right)
\end{split}\tag9
\end{equation}

Comment: I follow you until the (6) step. What are you essentially doing from there onwards?

Comment: Step (6) entails getting the angle of the transfer function as a function of frequency. In the numerator of (4), \$\angle j C_2 R_2 \omega = 2 \pi \$. Each factor in the denominator has real part equal to 1 and imaginary parts equal to \$\omega C_1 R_1\$ and \$ \omega C_2 R_2\$.  In the complex plane these are right triangles with angles equal to  \$\arctan\left( \omega C_1 R_1\right)\$ and \$\arctan\left( \omega C_2 R_2\right)\$.  As they are in the denominator, they should be subtracted from the angle in the numerator.  The rest just deals with a (common) special case.

Comment: @JohnnyB If you take a look at my edit, I show mathematically how I got the expressions.

Comment: @CharlesB.Cameron you stated in your comment that \$\arg\left(\text{j}\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\right)\$ equals \$2\pi\$ which is wrong, because \$\arg\left(\text{j}\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

### Straight KCL Solution

The KCL for the four nodes is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{R_1}v_1+s C_1\, v1&=\frac1{R_1}v_{in}\tag{1}
\\\\
s C_2\,v_2&=i_1\tag{2}
\\\\
\frac{1}{R_2}v_3+s C_2\, v3&=s C_2\,v_2\tag{3}
\\\\
0&=i_2\tag{4}
\end{align*}$$

*(\$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$ are the opamp output currents.)*

But you also know that \$v_2=v_1\$ and that \$v_{out}=v_3\$. You should be able to fill out your matrices from this and use the Schur complement method to solve from there.

But cheating and just using a solver:

```
from sympy import *                     # required once per session
from sympy.solvers import solve         # required once per session
e1 = Eq( v1/r1 + s*c1*v1, vin/r1 )      # KCL/nodal for v1
e2 = Eq( s*c2*v2, i1 )                  # KCL/nodal for v2
e3 = Eq( v3/r2 + s*c2*v3, s*c2*v2 )     # KCL/nodal for v3
e4 = Eq( 0, i2 )                        # KCL/nodal for vout
e5 = Eq( v2, v1 )                       # left ideal opamp
e6 = Eq( vout, v3 )                     # right ideal opamp
ans = solve( [ e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6 ], [ i1, i2, v1, v2, v3, vout ] )
ans
{i1: c2*s*vin/(c1*r1*s + 1),
 v1: vin/(c1*r1*s + 1),
 v2: vin/(c1*r1*s + 1),
 v3: c2*r2*s*vin/(c1*c2*r1*r2*s**2 + c1*r1*s + c2*r2*s + 1),
 vout: c2*r2*s*vin/(c1*c2*r1*r2*s**2 + c1*r1*s + c2*r2*s + 1),
 i2: 0}
ans[vout]/vin
c2*r2*s/(c1*c2*r1*r2*s**2 + c1*r1*s + c2*r2*s + 1)
```

*(I'm using freely available [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) for this -- they run on a variety of environments and use the [Python](https://www.python.org/) language.)*

### Matrices

The full matrix looks more to me like this:

[image]

But as shown with blue lines, you can strike the last column and the bottom row.

Striking those and if you call the upper-left 4x4 \$P\$ such that the above matrix can then be expressed in block form: \$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}P&Q^T\\Q&R\end{smallmatrix}\right]\$. Then if your column vector is \$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\hat{v}\\\hat{e}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\$ and the result is \$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\hat{0}\\\hat{i}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\$ so that \$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}P&Q^T\\Q&R\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\hat{v}\\\hat{e}\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\hat{0}\\\hat{i}\end{smallmatrix}\right]\$, then \$\hat{v}=-P^{-1}Q^T\hat{e}\$.

```
P = Matrix([ [1/r1+s*c1,0,0,0], [-1,1,0,0], [0,-s*c2,1/r2+s*c2,0], [0,0,-1,1] ])
Q = Matrix([ [-1/r1,0,0,0] ])
ev = Matrix([ vin ])
for u in list( -P.inv()*Q.transpose()*ev ): simplify( u/vin )
1/(c1*r1*s + 1)                                      # v1
1/(c1*r1*s + 1)                                      # v2
c2*r2*s/(c1*c2*r1*r2*s**2 + c1*r1*s + c2*r2*s + 1)   # v3
c2*r2*s/(c1*c2*r1*r2*s**2 + c1*r1*s + c2*r2*s + 1)   # vout
```

Same result.

### Bandpass

It's a bandpass, of course. If \$\tau_{_1}=R_1 C_1\$ and \$\tau_{_2}=R_2 C_2\$ then \$K=\frac1{1+\frac{\tau_{_1}}{\tau_{_2}}}\$, \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\sqrt{\tau_{_1} \tau_{_2}}}\$, and \$\zeta=\frac12\omega_{_0}\left(\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}\right)\$ or \$Q=\frac1{\omega_{_0}\left(\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}\right)}\$. Those can be plugged into the standard 2nd order bandpass transfer function form of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a complete analysis. I hope the user's request is understandable and satisfactory.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Much respect for copy-pasting the entire MathCad notebook here :) It’s certainly, ah, not typical approach taken, but hey it works. Perhaps you could find a plug-in/script that outputs in latex, then you could paste text here.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer with additional details rather than posting additional answers (e.g. your answer that began with "Clarification regarding my previous comment:").

Comment: MATHCAD 15 gives me the ability to create a PDF of the worksheet I created. Not knowing how to upload it here, I make copies with Paint page by page and publish them.